# Same queries in mongodb shell and node.js act different

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Why this is happening? Is there a logical explanation for this difference?

For example I have a db structure as;

```
{
    id: "1"
    category: {
      name: "name1"
      groups: [
         {
             groupName : "groupName1"
             title: ""
         },
         {
             groupName : "groupName2"
             title: ""
         }
      ]
    }
}
```

Query is the following;

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$category.groups"},
                        {$match:{"category.groups.groupName": "groupName2", 
                        "category.name" : "name1"}})
```

In mongo shell it returns as;

```
   {
        id: "1"
        category: {
          name: "name1"
          groups: [
             groupName : "groupName2"
             title: ""
          ]
        }
    }
```

Query in node.js;

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$category.groups"},
                        {$match:{"category.groups.groupName": "groupName2",
                        "category.name" : "name1"}}).
                        toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
     debugger;
     var res = result;
    } 
  });
};
```

where in node.js result is like;

```
{
    id: "1"
    category: {
      name: "name1"
      groups: [
         {
         groupName : "groupName1"
         title: ""
         },
         {
         groupName : "groupName2"
         title: ""
         }
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide with an example query which is behaving this way..

Comment: what is the difference, you should be more explicit

Comment: I edited my question, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I added node.js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the node.js driver, you need to pass your [`aggregate`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#aggregate) pipeline as an array, not as separate parameters.

So it should be:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$category.groups"},
                         {$match: {"category.groups.groupName": "groupName2",
                                  "category.name": "name1"}}
                        ]).toArray(function(err, result) { ... });
```

The [shell version](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) is more forgiving, but to be safe, you should always use an array as you can't include an `options` parameter otherwise.